# fantasy-land confusion on ap method signature

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, sanctuary, fantasyland, folktale

In [fantasy-land spec](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#apply), the signature for `ap` method is defined as

```hs
fantasy-land/ap :: Apply f => f a ~> f (a -> b) -> f b
```

This translates as: The `container f with value a` has a method `ap` which takes a parameter `container f` with value of a function `(a ->b)` and returns a `container f with value b`. I hope I am right in this interpretation.

If I test this with Folktale, However I see different results:

```js
const Maybe = require("data.maybe")
Maybe.of(5).ap(Maybe.of(x => x + 1)) // Uncaught TypeError: f is not a function
Maybe.of(x=>x+1).ap(Maybe.of(5))     // Maybe { value: 6 }
Maybe.of(x=>x+1).ap(Either.of(5))    // Either { value: 6 }
```

If I test this with Sanctuary, I see similar results (though Sanctuary does not have it as a "method")

```js
const S = require("sanctuary")
let a = S.of(S.Maybe)(5)
let fn = S.of(S.Maybe)(x => x + 1)
S.ap(fn)(a) // Just (6)
S.ap(a)(fn) // Uncaught TypeError: Invalid value
```

This brings me to the conclusion that perhaps the fantasy-land specs for `ap` method could be:

```hs
fantasy-land/ap :: Apply f => f (a -> b) ~> f a -> f b
```

I am a newbie on FP and fantasy-land as well. I am happy to get corrected :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fantasyland specifies an interoperability layer, not a public API (although it use to be the case), hence the `fantasy-land/` prefix which would otherwise not be user friendly at all. As a result you can find different conventions in different libraries. Oftentimes libraries implement both `ap` and `fantasy-land/ap`, with the arguments flipped.

The specification for `ap` also changed at some point. Some articles still mention the old spec. As for implementations, they don't want to break their users and the old spec is arguably easier to use (you can chain `ap` calls).

Comment: Understood. Thanks! I also agree that the old spec (which I understand now as 1.x) is better for chaining `ap` calls (and it reads better too)